# Notifications about new answers or comments doesn't work

Tags: support, notifications

Today (one hour ago) I posted a question: [History from SQL Agent Jobs (SQL Server 2005)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44293/history-from-sql-agent-jobs-sql-server-2005)

All notifications about new answer(s)/comments were accessible only when I checked my question on the Database Administrators site manually, not notified outside of Database Administrators.

During this time (question asked, commented, accepted) I have been active on another SO site.

Interestingly, notifications from another site (SO) here work.

Comment: That is strange, I have always received notification to my global inbox from DBA.SE.

Comment: @bluefeet maybe you're just special

Comment: @swasheck Maybe but I just got the comment notification in my inbox.

Comment: @bluefeet I had the runs this morning.

Comment: @bluefeet let's test it, though I believe it will work because of dark magic.

Comment: @Marian does it work for you?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO no comment

Comment: @bluefeet smoke test executed successfully :-).

Comment: @bluefeet I was notified about your no comment.

Comment: Are you by any chance logged in from multiple places?

Comment: @wax eagle not I'm not, 08:00 - 16:00 CET I'm logged for one IP, then from second, because my avatar is changed from green to blue, I think that both are static, never needed this info,  today one time, only to check notifications from cell_bridge :-), but before / during lunch time

Comment: @mKorbel an avatar change indicates and *email address* change not an IP change. The avatar is generated from a hash of your email. That might be the hiccup. http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/

Comment: @wax eagle this is not true at all, on [SO + SO_meta](http://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel) I have (in office) blue avatar (and rest of SO sites) , in home I have green avatar (as you can see right now on my SO), about this abnormality :-) I was asked a few times, EDIT loggin access by using MyOpenID

Comment: This looks like it was a temporary glitch. Are you still missing your DBA notifications when looking from SO? (Get a screenshot if you can.)

Comment: @Abby T. Miller 1. `Are you still missing your DBA ...`, can't confirm or because I have't any question here, 2. `Get a screenshot if you can.` agree I'll notify about on DBA_meta, 3. this isn't a new issue, because caused once time before and only on DBA

Comment: @mKorbel Sounds like a weird glitch. Keep an eye out for it - if it happens again, throw a screenshot up and we'll tag this with [meta-tag:bug] to get it figured out.